# Powershell parsing parsing error ".*\((?KB\d{6,7})\)" - Unrecognized grouping construct

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, parsing, windows-update

Hi I'm trying to play with windows updates with PowerShell script, the script works fine but before results it through parsing error.

**my script**

```powershell
$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session            
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()            
$HistoryCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()            
# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx            
$Searcher.QueryHistory(0,$HistoryCount) | ForEach-Object -Process {            
    $Title = $null            
    if($_.Title -match "\(KB\d{6,7}\)"){            
        # Split returns an array of strings            
        $Title = ($_.Title -split '.*\((?KB\d{6,7})\)')[1]            
    }else{            
        $Title = $_.Title            
    }            
    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx            
    $Result = $null            
    Switch ($_.ResultCode)            
    {            
        0 { $Result = 'NotStarted'}            
        1 { $Result = 'InProgress' }            
        2 { $Result = 'Succeeded' }            
        3 { $Result = 'SucceededWithErrors' }            
        4 { $Result = 'Failed' }            
        5 { $Result = 'Aborted' }            
        default { $Result = $_ }            
    }            
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{            
        InstalledOn = Get-Date -Date $_.Date;            
        Title = $Title;            
        Name = $_.Title;            
        Status = $Result            
    }            
            
} | Sort-Object -Descending:$true -Property nInstalledO |             
Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty Name | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

above script works fine but before results it shows some parsing error at line

**error:**

```
parsing ".*\((?KB\d{6,7})\)" - Unrecognized grouping construct.
At B:\Clients\SirAhmad\check-updates-history.ps1:9 char:9
+         $Title = ($_.Title -split '.*\((?KB\d{6,7})\)')[1]
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

at line

`$Title = ($_.Title -split '.*\((?KB\d{6,7})\)')[1]`

Looks regx issues.

Can someone help me out to indicate what is the issue with regix?

Comment: it seems like you wanted to have a named capture group, in which case, the pattern would be `.*\((?<KB>\d{6,7})\)`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon OMG, Thank you sooo much...that made my day.. Please post it as answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon To me it looks like `KB` is actually part of the search pattern (Windows updates are named like `KB123456`). So the `?` is propably meant to be `?:` (non-capturing group). Doesn't really make sense to me anyway.

Comment: @zett42 i dont know, my comment was what first came to mind. OP can confirm what he needed

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon i don't know much about regex, as i hate it even in my school. But that worked for me which u mentioned in the comment.